# How to build a jar without dependencies (library jars) using ant in android?

Tags: android, ant, jar, dependencies, publish

My library project include several library jars.

I want to publish a jar without dependencies of my library project.

How to build it using ant?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need generate module_name_of_project.xml and include jar on target, below screen-shots works on **Mac OS** and **Intellij IDEA**.

— First step generate **module_name_of_project.xml**

[image: 1]

— Write your output module name

[image: 1]

— Second step write on new generated file, between:

`<target name="compile.module.MODULE_NAME.production" ... </target>`

this:

```
<jar destfile="${MODULE_NAME.output.dir}/JAR_NAME.jar"
             basedir="${MODULE_NAME.output.dir}"/>
```

After you need just write `ant` on **terminal** (console), also you need be in project folder.

Can be useful: [How install ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html)